# Error: "Conditions must be prefaced by a vendor." on creating Role in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am getting an error of "Conditions must be prefaced by a vendor." when trying to use the AWS CDK to create a new role.

```js
export const configureIAMRole = (scope: Construct) => {
  const roleAction = 'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity';
  const iamRole = new Role(scope, 'IAMRole', {
    assumedBy: new FederatedPrincipal(
      'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com',
      {
        StringEquals: { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': identityPool.ref },
        'ForAnyValue:StringLike': { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': 'authenticated' },
      },
      roleAction
    ),
  });
  return iamRole;
};
```

There are docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html) which I tried to follow to add the vendor prefix e.g. "aws:StringEquals". That resulted in other errors e.g. invalid syntax.

The intention is to use Cognito for auth: user and pass, plus federated identities e.g. google. 
Thanks in advance for hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example iam role app with identity pool:

https://github.com/cloudshiftstrategies/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/iam-role-typescript-app

Looks like you forgot to add :aud to the end of 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com' in the StringEquals.  Should be

```
'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.ref
```